# Populating Ember JS handlebars template with Ajax data from model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js

## the scenario.

I'm gathering some ajax data and want to populate a list with it. The data source is from LastFM's API - I know I'm receiving the data - see the image:

[image: image showing data in ember view]

Here's the code I'm using - any advice on best practice would be appreciated also - I'm enjoying Ember, but to be honest am still feeing my way around the way it works:

## ember model

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {

      var albumArtwork = [];

      function convertString (data) {
          return encodeURIComponent(data).replace(/%20/g, "+");
      }

      $.each(topAlbums, function (i, el) {
          var request = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=[REMOVED API KEY!]&artist=' + convertString(topAlbums[i].artist) + '&album=' + convertString(topAlbums[i].album) + '&format=json';

          $.ajax({
              'url': request
          }).done(function (d) {
              albumArtwork.push(d.album.image[1]['#text']);
          });
      });

      albumArtwork = _.toArray(albumArtwork)

      return albumArtwork;
  }
  });
```

## ember handlebars template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <div class="album-artwork-list-wrapper">
        <ul class="album-artwork-list">
            {{#each item in model}}
                <li class="album-artwork-item">
                    <img src="{{item}}">
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </dv>
</script>
```

## final thoughts

Here's what I think is happening: The handlebars template is being rendered before the data comes back from the API call. How to overcome this with Ember JS, I'm not certain - I have seen examples of a solution here on stackoverflow and attempted to use them but to no avail!

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to create promises so that async calls can become synchronised. Ember provides RSVP.js to do the same. RSVP.all fits your purpose. So..your code can be changed like this.

```
    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function () {

          var albumArtwork = [], promises =[];

          function convertString (data) {
              return encodeURIComponent(data).replace(/%20/g, "+");
          }

          $.each(topAlbums, function (i, el) {
              var request = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=[REMOVED API KEY!]&artist=' + convertString(topAlbums[i].artist) + '&album=' + convertString(topAlbums[i].album) + '&format=json';

              promises.push(ajaxPromise(url));

      }
      return RSVP.all(promises).then(function(images) {
             // images contains an array of results for the given promises
             albumArtwork = images.filterBy('album');
             return albumArtwork;
          });
      });

var ajaxPromise = function(url, options){
  return Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    options.success = function(data){
      resolve(data);
    };

    options.error = function(jqXHR, status, error){
      reject(arguments);
    };

    Ember.$.ajax(url, options);
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried using your code - it required some editing, however, I'm getting the error: **'Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: undefined is not a function'** - do you know why this may be the case?

Comment: think its may not be returning data in right format...anyways can you please share the code in Jsbin..you can use this.. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/